# Hooks for "smart" elements

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Is there any simple/elegant way in C++11, via STL or boost, to make an element-type "smart" so that an instance of it always knows which container it belongs to and has member functions for a sort of "auto-removal" which also takes care of updating the container it is part of?

The real case is that I have a callback C-function (from a C library) being called after a given request has been completed. This function accepts a raw pointer to the element which has been processed. Now what I want is to remove this element from the list it belongs to and move it to another list.

I know I could store a pointer to the container in the element itself and when the callback is called I could iterate over that container until I find the element, then remove it and call `newlist.push_back(object)`. Given that one element must live in one container (and only one), I wonder if there's something more elegant.

Comment: What do you mean of "auto-removal"? You want to have cachemap of weak pointers?

Comment: the only reasonable use case i can think of is where you hand out a raw pointer to the item to some other code, which should be able to delete the item. for that use case i suggest instead handing out a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr`. then with your container a container of such smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost's [intrusive containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/intrusive/presenting_containers.html) implement that functionality.

This requires specific containers as well as objects specifically designed to work with the containers, however.

Comment: Would it be possible to push_back() one element to a new boost::intrusive::list so that it also eventually removes the element presence from any old intrusive list?

Comment: I think I can achieve what I want with boost::intrusive by unlinking and pushing_back() to a new list.